# use other value if current if null

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, where-clause, sql-null

I have next code:

```
AND (some_date >= prog_start)
```

what I need if use other value to compare if `some_date` is null.
something like:

```
AND (some_date ? some_date : now() >= prog_start)
```

how I can do it in sql?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `coalesce()`:

```
where coalesce(some_date, now()) >= prog_start
```

`coalesce()` returns its first non-`null` argument. So when `some_date` is `null`, the above expression returns `now()` instead, which is then compared against `prog_start`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a NULL statement you will do something like this:

```
SELECT prog_start FROM program WHERE some_date IS NULL;
```

The NULL statement is looking for any field that does not have a value, as opposed to maybe a 0 or empty string.